# How to extract a superclass to encapsulate common code?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, superclass

I have an application which uses plugins. After creating several of them I've found that a big chunk of code is repeated here and there on them so I want to extract a super "plugin base".

Previous the refactor I had the following structure:

[image: previous structure]

After the refactor I have the next one:

[image: current structure]

I currently don't find a way to model the fact that the plugin engine has a property *settings* of type *plugin settings* and the *plugin engine base* has a property *settings* of type *plugin settings base*. I feel that somehow should be a way to declare that the settings property of the plugin engine base should be a "cast" of the settings property of the *plugin engine* and to model the fact that they both are the same property.

I'm not sure if the problem is explained enough. Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach I found:

Base class:

```
class PluginEngineBase
{
    public PluginSettingsBase Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Inheritor:

```
class PluginEngine : PluginEngineBase
{
    public PluginSettings Settings
    {
        get
        {
            return (PluginSettings)base.Settings;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Settings = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics. Create generic base class and specify generic parameter constraint to be of type `PluginSettingsBase`.

```
abstract class PluginEngineBase<T>
   where T: PluginSettingsBase
{
   public abstract T Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Inherit from base class parametrized by `PluginsSettings` class (thus it is inherited from `PluginSettingsBase`)

```
class PluginEngine : PluginEngineBase<PluginsSettings>
{
   public PluginSettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Same with `PluginData`.

Comment: Mmmmm, I didn't thought on generics. Nice ... let me think on it. I usually feel generics confusing outside collections and that kind of stuff where the generics fit more naturally, but I'll take a look for sure. Thanks.